# installing nant with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, nant, environment-variables

I have a nant build file which numerous users have to run locally. Is there an easy way to automate the process of installing nant/nantcontrib and updating the matching environment variables on a windows system.

I have thought off a solution where a folder containing the nant/contrib files and a batch script is copied to each station. When the batch script is executed the nant dll's should be copied to a meaning full location and the env varialbes should be updated.

Is that the right way to go about this?

thanks / dres

Answer (score 3):

I normally check NAnt into the repos with the source, then have a couple of batch files to the various targets. I know this doesn't exactly answer your question but it possibly solves the underlying problem.

Edit re: comments

my directory structure looks like this:

```
/src
/lib
/tools/nant
/project.sln
/project.build
/build.bat
/deploy.bat
```

Comment: Hi Andrew

Maybe this is the right answer to my question. Would you be kind to elaborate a bit on your solution or maybe just a link to a describtion of a similar setup.

Regards / dres

Comment: I see - an elegant way of calling the build script and assigning property values specific for the various tasks (build, test, deploy). 

But this does not solve how the nant installation is distributed to each dev client machine. Since we work with virtual machines I guess a solution to my problem would be to simply install nant on the base image and distribute that. 

regards / dresen

Comment: no, but with this solution is doesnt need to be, your build.bat has: tools/nant/bin/nant.exe project.build build